# Time formats depending on language in timescale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a timechart in d3 with a zoomable timescale.
The ticks change when zooming in or out.
This is my code, which works perfectly.

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([ new Date(minDate), new Date(maxDate) ]).range([ 0, width ]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").ticks(5);
```

However the months and days are displayed in English. My website can be viewed in different languages. So I would like to translate the timeformat to a different language, depending on the language of the user.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think there's anything in D3 that will do this out of the box, but you can provide your own [`tickFormat` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat).

Comment: Please take a look at "How to make localization on months / days for D3js?" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274464/how-to-make-localization-on-months-days-for-d3js/20299137