# d3.js - time scale label in languages other than English

Tags: d3.js, internationalization, label

I have realized a line chart with AngularJS and d3. 
The x-axis shows a time scale over months (Feb to Oct). So the ticks are labeled with February, March, ... October.
How can I get the ticks in other languages than English?
For example if my app is in German I like to have the German month names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make localization on months / days for D3js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274464/how-to-make-localization-on-months-days-for-d3js)

Comment: @Lars: I've read your advice to recompile d3.js (and d3.min.js) on a machine with the locale settings.  So for a multilingual app I must have versions of d3.js / d3.min.js in all the supported languages and then decide which script to include? Is there no other way? As I'm new to AngularJS and d3 any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Having multiple versions would certainly be the easiest way. You can also modify D3 to include the array of names from some other source, but that would require more effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Lars is working: Recompiling d3.js on a machine with German settings and including d3.de_DE.js instead of d3.js gives the time-scale with German names. 
In the source you find the files 
src/time/format-localized.js and
src/format/format-localized.js with the English settings.

Comment: Unfortunately any patched library complicates update processes.  Mike Bostock commited on a locale-branch to this issue. It seems to be a first draft, but maybe it is helpful for you. Please take a look at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/30590de15f9b7cccf3fe4cc656702c2dfcc287ea