# How to use d3.js custom locale?

Tags: d3.js

I dont find any example for how to use d3.locale.
D3.js Documentation page says we have to set variable while putting.
But i am not clear about this.
Can any one help me, how to use d3.locale time format or suggest any examples

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274464/how-to-make-localization-on-months-days-for-d3js) may help.