# Locale for axis nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

How to change the locale on axis labels? By default US locale is used for numbers ','(comma) as thousand separator while I need to change it to '.'
Thanks

Comment: You need to rebuild D3, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Localization).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, does the doc explain how to load new locales as needed? Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the link I've posted above, it doesn't seem to explain how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Locale-Unaware version:

```
commaFormat = d3.format(',')
chart = nv.models.lineChart();
chart.xAxis().tickFormat(commaFormat);
chart.yAxis().tickFormat(commaFormat);
```

You will need to do this for every axis on every chart.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/19275327/240358 is on the right track.

From the 2.10 release, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/753 has info on rebuilding d3 with a locale. Built-in locale files are at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/src/locale

As you asked in relation to nvd3, you'll want to fork d3 on github, run the build, commit that bin/ on a separate branch, and push that to your fork. Then in your project that uses nvd3, you can use that branch - if you're using bower for your dependencies, specify your branch and repo as the dependency.

I am now considering building and hosting local versions.

Comment: Thanks David, But I don't know how to do this :-) And to be honest I don't think it worths the pain (from my point of view)!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how I missed this earlier, but the latest d3 localization allows runtime definition loading.

```
d3.locale({
    thousands: ".",
    decimal: ","
});
# nvd3 charting code.
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Localization

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply I've already checked the link you send but I couldn't make it work even on a simple d3.js sample (not nvd3.js) like the one http://fiddle.jshell.net/zUj3E/2/ after the necessary modifications in order to have decimal on axis it didn't work.

Comment: How do you use the above code snippet? where do you store it? can you make a dynamic selection with a user button? any hint/url appreciated.